# Here Map Navigator Not Opening Using Guidance-drive in Phonegap[Nokia x support android Platform] Application Error or Protocol not supported error

Tags: android, cordova, here-api, nokiax

I use Cordova.jar 2.9.0.
Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#BtnNavigation").click(function () {
                    alert("dfgdfgh");
                    window.location.assign("guidance-drive://v2.0/navigate/destination/?latlon='25.245789','75.254789'&title=Hello World");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>   
         "http://example.com"
         <button id="BtnNavigation" name="Map" style="padding: 50px 100px;">Map</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Button click shows error:

```
The Protocol Not Supported(guidance-drive://v2.0/navigate/destination/?latlon='25.245789','75.254789'&title=Hello World)
```

> some text to get rid of "it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"

Answer (score 0):

The Url Scheme used with Windows Phone 8 devices is not implemented with Nokia X devices, and thus you can not use it with Nokia X devices. Also as far as I know, there is no public offering for HERE Drive usage implemented with Nokia X, thus I could not even suggest any alternative API to use.